# rails conditional missaligning boostrap table

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Hello was working on a task management app to practice after watching some tutorials (Total noob here), but when styling it with boostrap my I've got an if statement inside of a bootstrap table that the items inside get misaligned when the conditional is inside the table, the second I take it out everything lines up again.

Here's my code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgvwxc0u19r0gcl/Screenshot%202017-03-18%2022.44.32.png?dl=0

Here's what's doing (see how the items aren't aligning): https://www.dropbox.com/s/x7n6tn4l5teah5l/Screenshot%202017-03-18%2022.45.16.png?dl=0

I've tried giving them each classes of they're own and trying to align it in CSS but that seems like it's not doing anything at all.

Any ideas why this is happening and what the solution may be?
Rails 4.2.5 and bootstrap-sass gem

Thanks in advance any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why you put width attribute on td in one conditional?

Comment: @rails_id my bad... forgot to take it off, I added a 1px red border attribute to visualize what the table was doing and I was trying to set a fixed width to it, I took off already I just forgot to update the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [Panels](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels) from bootstrap. You can set some nice layouts without having to deal with tables.

e.g.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Edit | Delete
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">check</div>
        <div class="col-lg-7">name</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">delete</div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you can paste in your code then I can show you an example related to your scenario.

Comment: Tnx a lot michael I'm gona experiment some more with it, this code is actually a partial and I'm using a panel already in the show.html.erb page where the code in question is being rendered inside of the body of the panel. Will try put my code in the partial inside of a panel as well and play with that.